# Memory management - operating system - Page table Entry

Tags: operating-system

Kindly explain page table entry as according to my understanding total page table size = number of pages *size of each page where number of pages is given in the logical address and offset is the page size. So how page table entry is applicable and when to use?

Comment: See also https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging

Answer (score 1):

**Page table entry** forms a single entry or a row inside a page table. We get to the correct entry of page table using **page number** of **virtual address**.

[image]

After getting to the correct entry of page table, the entry gives us the correct **physical page number** or **frame number of physical memory** and we use the **offset** to get to the correct **byte(in case word = byte) or word**.

This means **size of page table = number of entries in page table * size of single page table entry**.

Number of entries in page table is = **2 to the power of virtual page number** as it is in binary.